# ¿Problema con AngularJS al usar el metodo POST?

Tags: angularjs, post

Los datos se envían pero al verificar en la base de datos no se guardan.

hago la prueba con postman hacia la API y si funciona.

Me comentaron, que tengo que definir que la petición que esta saliendo sea de formulario aunque no lo sea.

Podrían ayudarme por favor, gracias.

```
$scope.crear = function () {
        
        var strProducto = $scope.nproducto.tipo + ' ' + $scope.nproducto.marca;

        var data = {
            'strMarca': $scope.nproducto.marca, 'strModelo': $scope.nproducto.tipo,
            'intIdUsuario': 11, 'strProducto': strProducto
        };
        var settings = {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/index.php/producto",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },

            "data": data
        }
        var request = $http(settings);
        request.then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
            .catch('error ' + console.error);

    }
```

Comment: Nunca lo hice de la forma que lo haces, probá asi:
var conAjax = $http.post("http://localhost:8080/index.php/producto", {data);
conAjax.success(function(respuesta){
     console.log(respuesta);
});